# Angular material navigation bar not aligned

Tags: angular

I followed these articles to setup my Angular project environment:

- https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started
- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart
- https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics

After the *ng* project is created, I added the material navigation schema.

```
ng g @angular/material:material-nav --name mat-nav
```

Then I replaced the content of the default `app.component.html` file with the new navigation component.

```
<app-mat-nav></app-mat-nav>
```

Then I imported the material theme in the `styles.scss` file.

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

At last, I started the server. There was no error during the compilation, nor error in the browser. But my page layout looks like below.

*Note the white strip above the title bar.*

[image]

## Update

Confirmed by Google, it is not a [bug](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12133#issuecomment-403826733). It's only a strange feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default CSS margin is added in the body tag. Add following code in styles.scss file

```
* {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

You can also use normalize.css or reset.css file to overwrite the default browser styles.

Comment: I generated a **new** project with the latest **cli**, but I don't see that default style anywhere.

Comment: These are user-agent styles. These default styles are not part of your application.

Comment: You can check this in the browser (chrome) by following the below steps. 

1. Right click on your page 
2. Select inspect element 
3. Select body tag from element tab
4. You will see body tag styles on the right side.

Comment: So, you don't need *margin: 0* or `normalize.css`, and everything works on your machine?